# Display particular value in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

here is my portion of  Json which I converted to Df

`{"business_id": "vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA", "full_address": "4840 E Indian School Rd\nSte 101\nPhoenix, AZ 85018", "hours": {"Tuesday": {"close": "17:00", "open": "08:00"}, "Friday": {"close": "17:00", "open": "08:00"}, "Monday": {"close": "17:00", "open": "08:00"}, "Wednesday": {"close": "17:00", "open": "08:00"}, "Thursday": {"close": "17:00", "open": "08:00"}}, "open": true, "categories": ["Doctors", "Health & Medical"], "city": "Phoenix", "review_count": 9, "name": "Eric Goldberg, MD", "neighborhoods": [], "longitude": -111.98375799999999, "state": "AZ", "stars": 3.5, "latitude": 33.499313000000001, "attributes": {"By Appointment Only": true}, "type": "business"}`... and many more like this

Now I need to display only Tuesday opening and close timing of all business.I tried with help of `isin` with `filter`condition .But that did not work ..Anyone please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dataframe is loaded correctly with this schema (I loaded your example with `spark.read.json`):

```
    scala> df.printSchema
    root
    |-- attributes: struct (nullable = true)
    |    |-- By Appointment Only: boolean (nullable = true)
    |-- business_id: string (nullable = true)
    |-- categories: array (nullable = true)
    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
    |-- full_address: string (nullable = true)
    |-- hours: struct (nullable = true)
    |    |-- Friday: struct (nullable = true)
    |    |    |-- close: string (nullable = true)
    |    |    |-- open: string (nullable = true)
    |    |-- Monday: struct (nullable = true)
    |    |    |-- close: string (nullable = true)
    |    |    |-- open: string (nullable = true)
    |    |-- Thursday: struct (nullable = true)
    |    |    |-- close: string (nullable = true)
    |    |    |-- open: string (nullable = true)
    |    |-- Tuesday: struct (nullable = true)
    |    |    |-- close: string (nullable = true)
    |    |    |-- open: string (nullable = true)
    |    |-- Wednesday: struct (nullable = true)
    |    |    |-- close: string (nullable = true)
    |    |    |-- open: string (nullable = true)
    |-- latitude: double (nullable = true)
    |-- longitude: double (nullable = true)
    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
    |-- neighborhoods: array (nullable = true)
    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
    |-- open: boolean (nullable = true)
    |-- review_count: long (nullable = true)
    |-- stars: double (nullable = true)
    |-- state: string (nullable = true)
    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
```

you can do

```
    scala> df.select("hours.Tuesday").show
    +--------------+
    |       Tuesday|
    +--------------+
    |[17:00, 08:00]|
    +--------------+
```

if you want just close time you can do

```
scala> df.select("hours.Tuesday.close").show
+-----+
|close|
+-----+
|17:00|
+-----+
```

Comment: ,Thank u for your suggestion.cant we use like   val day=spark.sql("select hours.open,hours.close from <tbl_name>").filter(col("hours")==="tuesday").show() ?

Comment: When reading json, if Tuesday is not present for one record, it will still be in the schema because of other records that have it, so you want to do something like ` df.createOrReplaceTempView("t")` and then `spark.sql("select hours.Tuesday from t where hours.Tuesday is not null")`